# How to add custom confirmation dialog box with Visualforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

As my Apex code show in below,

when once user execute 'saveSearchItems' action with 'apex:commandButton',
if result of the validation got 'false', 
I want to show confirmation dialog box to user message with 'Validation failed, do you want to continue?'.

When user press 'OK' button I want to save the items (by executing saveSearchItems method) and if user press 'NO' I want to stop the saving (do nothing).

Can anyone please tell me how I can achieve this with Apex & Visualforce.
Thanks a lot.

```
 /**
  * Save list of SearchItems 
  */
 public void saveSearchItems()  { 

    // Validate values of SearchItems 
       Boolean validateResult = validateSearchItems(this.searchItemList);

    // Save SearchItems   
       saveSearchItems(this.searchItemList);         
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apex code executes at server, not at client so showing dialog boxes cannot happen from Apex. For that reason you will either have to move the validation to the client (using javascript onclick handler) or you will have to split the saving process in two Ajax calls to server, one to validate the other to save and then use the intermediary validation result to optionally show dialog box. The choice depends on the complexity of the validation (`validateSearchItems`)

Comment: Hi mmix! Thanks a lot for your great feedback. Have a nice time!

Answer (score 1):

While mmix is correct there actually is a way to simulate this, it just takes a little creative use of the apex:actionFunction and a dash of javascript. You're basically breaking the action down into two calls to deal with the reality of http's client/server model.

First is a validation call to determine if a popup should be displayed to the user, second is a call to save if needed based on the user response. Keep in mind that my solution depends on the javascript confirm box so no fancy ui here :)

*FYI - I did reference jquery in my example, just save a jquery minimized library as jquery.txt and add to your static resources with the name 'jquery' and you're good to go.*

Create a controller class with the following code:

```
public class ActionFunctionCLS {

public Boolean causeValidationWarning {get; set;} // Just used for controlling the test behavoir from the ui. Not a part of the solution.
public String validationWarning {get; set;}

// Validates the record (or whatever) is good. If it is then we call save, else we set a warning message that 
// tells the ui to display a javascript popup box to the user confirming they really want to proceed.
public PageReference ValidateAndSaveRecord() {
    PageReference result = null;

    if(causeValidationWarning){
      validationWarning = 'This is a validation warning, hit Ok if you\'re sure you want to proceed.';
    }
    else {
      validationWarning = '';
      result = SaveRecord();
    }
    return result;
}

// Clears the validation warning so the ui won't try and display a confirmation box to the user
public void clearvalidationWarning(){
   validationWarning = '';
}

// Actually saves the record and then performs some post save function. Could be anything from displaying a save message (which means
// we'd need to clear the validation warning to keep the confimation pop from appearing), or it could even be a redirect somewhere else.
public PageReference SaveRecord() {
    ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, 'Save Complete!', 'And I totally could have redirected you or something.');
    ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
  clearvalidationWarning();
    return null;
}

// Just to prove that our Validation & Save logic won't affect other functionality
public PageReference DoSomething() {
  ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'I did some other work.');
  ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
  return null;
}
```

}

Then create a visual force page:

```
<apex:page controller="ActionFunctionCLS" id="pg" showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery}"/>

<script>
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict(); //Needed for jQuery usage

    j$(document).ready(function(){           
        var validationWarningMsg = "{!validationWarning}";
        if(validationWarningMsg != ''){ // There was a validation warning, make sure the user still wants to save    
            if(confirm(validationWarningMsg)){
                saveRecordAction();
            }
            else {
                clearvalidationWarningAction();
            }
        }
    });
</script>

<apex:form id="myForm">
     <apex:pageMessages />
     <apex:actionfunction name="saveRecordAction" action="{!SaveRecord}" />
     <apex:actionfunction name="clearvalidationWarningAction" action="{!clearvalidationWarning}" />

     <apex:pageBlock tabStyle="Account">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save Record" action="{!ValidateAndSaveRecord}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Do Other Work" action="{!DoSomething}" />
       </apex:pageBlockButtons>

       <apex:pageBlockSection title="Stuff" columns="1" >
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!causeValidationWarning}" label="Cause a validation warning" />
       </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

And test away! The apex:actionFunction is one of my new favorites, it allows you to make direct ajax calls into controller methods from javascript with no ugly coding at all, pretty neat stuff.

What's happening here is that the save button is calling into ValidateAndSaveRecord(), which runs our imaginary validations and then actually saves if all looks good. If not it sets a string property on the controller and returns. The javascript on the page looks for this string on page load and if it finds it, the confirmation popup is displayed.

When the user clicks Ok another ajax call is made to Save() but skips validation since that's already been done. If they click cancel a call is still made to clear out the warning string so the next postback doesn't cause the page to show the popup again. *That step is very important!*

I think my solution might give some heartburn because it depends on that cancel call so heavily, but it's been pretty dependable in my experience. Enjoy.